# Repeating certain columns when merging two data frames of different length (pasting?)

Tags: r

I have two data frames for an event study and struggle a bit with preparing the data for the analysis. df1 has two rows with company ID and event date. Some companies have more than one event date, so the company ID is listed for every event date (which means there's more columns than unique company ID's). The other (df2) has share price of every company: row 1 is the company ID and every row below is share price for that specific firm at different dates which are specified in column 1.

I want to merge (or paste?) the two data frames so that for every company ID in df1, it will copy the information below the matching company ID (share price) of df2 to itself.

I've searched around for a solution, however it looks like I'm bad at searching at the moment because my searches yield no significant results. I've tried different merge commands and expand.grid, but I'm rusty in r.

```
df1 <- data.frame(X1 = c("Event date","Company ID"),
               X2 = c("2018-01-01","AA"),
               X3 = c("2017-05-03","BB"),
               X4 = c("2016-04-08","CC"),
               X5 = c("2015-02-02","BB"))
df2 <- data.frame(X1 = c("Date","2018-12-31","2018-01-01","2017-05-03","2016-12-31","2016-04-08","2015-02-02"),
               X2 = c("AA",100,102,101,98,99,99),
               X3 = c("BB",85,78,80,77,75,74),
               X4 = c("CC",55,53,54,55,54,54))


df-desired <- data.frame(X1 = c("Event date","Company ID","2018-12-31","2018-01-01","2017-05-03","2016-12-31","2016-04-08","2015-02-02"),
             X2 = c("2018-01-01","AA",100,102,101,98,99,99),
             X3 = c("2017-05-03","BB",85,78,80,77,75,74),
             X4 = c("2016-04-08","CC",55,53,54,55,54,54),
             X5 = c("2015-02-02","BB",85,78,80,77,75,74))
```

My current data is like df1 and df2 and my desired result is df-desired. I would appreciate if anyone could help me out with what command I should look into. I can't think of what command I should spend my efforts on, so I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction!

Comment: This is a really awkward format for your `data.frame`s (the first lines of `df1` and `df2` seem to contain the column names?); are you sure the example data is correct?

Comment: It's how my actual data looks at the moment, but it may be worse than I think? (it messes up the dates because I have text in the first rows of column 1, which is holding the dates). df1 could have "Event date" as name of row 1 and "Company ID" as name of row2 and the first column could be empty and have "Date" as name. df2 could have "Date" as name of first column and "Company ID" as name of row 1.

Comment: What is the goal of thous manipulations?

Comment: I'm doing an event study about certain events regarding companies, where I investigate if the events affect the share price. df1 contains information about when the events happened and for which company. df2 contains share prices for every company for the whole sample. So for every event date in df1, I need to fetch the share price for the specific firm in a time period that I specify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approximation is to use `dplyr::union()` function after column renaming:

```
colnames(df1) = df1[2,]
colnames(df1)[1] = "Date"

colnames(df2) = df2[1,]

dplyr::union(df1,df2)

#        Date         AA         BB         CC         BB
#1 2015-02-02         99         74         54         74
#2 2016-04-08         99         75         54         75
#3 2016-12-31         98         77         55         77
#4 2017-05-03        101         80         54         80
#5 2018-01-01        102         78         53         78
#6 2018-12-31        100         85         55         85
#7       Date         AA         BB         CC         BB
#8 Company ID         AA         BB         CC         BB
#9 Event date 2018-01-01 2017-05-03 2016-04-08 2017-05-03
```

You can finally remove that repeated row

Comment: Thanks! I've looked into it, and this looks great! For anyone reading and trying to replicate it with the code from the original post, I had to add as.character(unlist for it to work:
    colnames(df1) = as.character(unlist(df1[2,]))